RIP Greg Hildebrandt
Notable SF artist Greg Hildebrandt (SFE, Encyclopedia of Fantasy, Wikipedia) passed away on Hallowe'en 2024.  With his twin brother Tim, they rose to prominence in the 1970s as notable illustrators of Tolkien's work, leading to a 30-year series of Tolkien calendars.
Working mostly with Tim, the Brothers Hildebrandt, as they were usually credited, painted a number of other classic covers, including the original covers of The Sword of Shannara (Brooks), My Name is Legion (Zelazny), and a number of Elizabeth Boyer's books.  (As it turns out, I have all of these.)
They also collaborated with Jerry Nichols on an illustrated book, Urshurak, in 1979.
Greg mostly retired after his brother passed away in 2006, but we still remember them fondly.  Who can forget Princess Leia showing off way more leg than Lucas (at the time) wanted?

